# Typescript: Mapped type to make every property readonly except chosen properties

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

I ran into a challenge where I didn't want to keep rewriting multiple interfaces.

I need one interface to be fully writable, and also have a "copy" of that interface where all fields are readonly except those that I select to be writeable.

Typescript has mapped types which may allow this.

Answer (score 5):

```js
export type DeepReadOnly<T> = { readonly [key in keyof T]: DeepReadOnly<T[key]> };
export type DeepMutable<T> = { -readonly [key in keyof T]: DeepMutable<T[key]> };
export type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
export type DeepKeepMutable<T, K extends keyof T> = DeepReadOnly<Omit<T, K>> & DeepMutable<Pick<T, K>>;

// use as follows
let o: DeepKeepMutable<Metadata, 'time' | 'payload'>;
// this will keep time and payload writeable while the rest are readonly

// it is also possible to extend and modify these types with index signatures, optional properties and level of depth
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use TypeScript's [Readonly utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype):

```
type SomeType = {
  a: string;
};

const s: SomeType = {
  a: "can modify",
};

s.a = "new value";
// ^ Can modify

type ReadOnlyType = Readonly<SomeType>;

const r: ReadOnlyType = {
  a: "cannot modify",
};

r.a = "new value";
// ^ ERROR! - Cannot assign to 'a' because it is a read-only property.
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve that by using some utility types or mapped types directly. Consider following:

```
type MakeSomePropsReadonly<A, K extends keyof A> = Readonly<Pick<A, K>> & Omit<A, K>

type Original = {
    a: string,
    b: number,
    c: boolean
}
type Example = MakeSomePropsReadonly<Original, 'a'>
const example: Example  = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 1,
    c: true
}

example.a = 'b'; // error a property is readonly
example.b = 2; // ok it is not readonly
```

What our type `Readonly<Pick<A, K>> & Omit<A, K>` does is :

- `Readonly<Pick<A, K>>` - creates a type which has only keys picked by `K` and all all readonly. In result we get only part of the type which has only these keys we pick
- `& Omit<A, K>` we intersect the previous mapped typed with only readonly properties with the second part, so `Omit<A, K>` will create object which will have all fields which have different key then `K`

So we create a type by joining one type with all readonly properties with another with writable ones.

---

We can also do it another way around, so we have readonly interface as you describe and pick which fields are writable:

```
type MakeSomePropsWritable<A, K extends keyof A> = {
    -readonly [Key in K]: A[Key]
} & Omit<A, K>

type Original = {
    readonly a: string,
    readonly b: number,
    readonly c: boolean
}
type Example = MakeSomePropsWritable<Original, 'a'>
const example: Example  = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 1,
    c: true
}

example.a = 'b'; // this is now ok as we left it writable
example.b = 2; // this is an error as expected
```

Nothing different in this implementation except of:

- `-readonly [Key in K]: A[Key]` - we say we remove readonly from those fields by `-` prefix